# How to cast float to int in sympy (of Python)?

Tags: python, casting, sympy

I have a sympy  Float constant, e.g,

```
x=Float(3.2)
```

I need to transform the floats  to  integers, i.e,

```
x+Int(3)
```

Is there any built-in method in sympy that can transform Float(3.2) to Int(3)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Casting a floating-point number to a **SymPy integer**:

```
In [1]: a = 3.2

In [2]: b = Integer(a)

In [3]: b
Out[3]: 3
```

SymPy integers behave *mathematically* under division:

```
In [4]: b/2
Out[4]: 3/2
```

Casting the same floating-point number to a **Python integer**:

```
In [5]: c = int(a)

In [6]: c  
Out[6]: 3
```

In Python 3 or using future division, you can get back a floating point:

```
In [7]: c/2
Out[7]: 1.5
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `Integer()` method. It allows to convert the float to int. `Integer()` always brings the float down to a round figure.

Example from interpreter:

```
>>> a = 3.2
>>> b = Integer(a)
>>> b
3
```

Comment: That would cast it to a Python integer, not to a SymPy integer.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I should have red the question more carefully. I'll be more careful in the future. +1 on your answer. Thank you very much for your advise!